# Crop/hide HTML img tag instead of deforming/stretching it

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using Bootstrap 3 Carousel and the images get smaller to match the viewport. What I need is to maintain the height of the images, but instead of having the image stretches/deformed, I need it to be cut from both sides maybe.

Example (Bad):

[image: Bad view (current)]

Example (Good):

[image: Good view]

It doesn't matter what part of the image the slider shows, it's just important that it doesn't deform the image.

This is my carousel HTML:

```
<div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="position: absolute; top: 50px;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="./stylesheets/images/web-banner.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                TEST
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="./stylesheets/images/web-banner.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                TEST
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And this is the custom LESS I've written for it:

```
.carousel.slide {
    margin-top: -20px;

    img {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-height: 600px !important;
    }
}
```

I do not know how to start fixing this. I've no slight imagination how this would go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
.carousel.slide {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

img {

    min-height: 100px !important;

}

.carousel-inner
{
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Aborted sorry, you're right, I didn't test my code before, edited my post and tested this time.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter what part of the image is shown, you should:

- remove the width:100%, and set the actual image dimensions
- wrap the image in a div
- set a width:100% on the wrapping div
- set overflow:hidden on the wrapping div

Answer (score 0):

Use this LESS script:

```
.carousel.slide {
    margin-top: -20px;

    img {
        min-height: 600px !important;
    }
}
```

This will maintain the height of the images, but will scale width accordingly.